# Initialize array by the range

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, initialization, range

I need to create an array with all values in a range. I can't set values after creating it, because array must be constexpr.

```
template<int FIRST, int LAST>
struct Foo
{
    static constexpr int array[LAST - FIRST + 1] = ???;
};
```

For exemple `Foo<3, 7>::array;`

should be equivalent to `static constexpr int array[5] = {3, 4, 5, 6, 7};`.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it can be done in C++11. No, it's not pretty. You essentially need to reimplement C++14's compile-time integer sequences.

```
///////////////// Reimplement compile-time integer sequences ///////////////////////
// There's plenty of better implementations around.
// This one is similar to libstdc++'s implementation.
template<class T, T... Ints>
struct integer_seq {
    using next = integer_seq<T, Ints..., sizeof...(Ints)>;
    static constexpr std::size_t size() { return sizeof...(Ints); }
};

template<class T, int Len>
struct seq_builder{
    static_assert(Len > 0, "Length must be nonnegative");
    using type = typename seq_builder<T, Len-1>::type::next;
};

template<class T>
struct seq_builder<T, 0>{
    using type = integer_seq<T>;
};

template<class T, int length>
using make_int_sequence = typename seq_builder<T, length>::type;

/////////////////// Actual stuff starts here/////////////////////////////////

template<int FIRST, int LAST, class = make_int_sequence<int, LAST+1-FIRST>>
struct Foo;

template<int FIRST, int LAST, int... SEQ>
struct Foo<FIRST, LAST, integer_seq<int, SEQ...>>
{
    static constexpr int array[sizeof...(SEQ)] = {(FIRST+SEQ)...};
};

template<int FIRST, int LAST, int... SEQ>
constexpr int Foo<FIRST, LAST, integer_seq<int, SEQ...>>::array[sizeof...(SEQ)];
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40720e279a500297).

Comment: Wow. I was JUST about to copy-paste my answer in and the code is EXACTLY the same as yours -- http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f8812cc2d431f550

Comment: @user2030677 something about great minds something :)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible in the proposed [C++14](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Relaxed_constexpr_restrictions) standard. I don't think it's possible with C++11.

If you really must do that, and don't just have a few such arrays that you can hard-code, you can resort to C macros. Apparently there are some libraries that [help you perform loops in macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117228/for-loop-macro-which-unrolled-on-the-pre-processor-phase) .